# CDocTemplate and m_templateList

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am upgrading some software from 16 bit to 32 bit in VC++ using MFC, and I understand that in recent versions of MFC I can no longer access m_templateList in `CDocTemplate`, I must use `GetFirstDocTemplatePosition` and `GetNextDocTemplate` instead. That is no problem as far as enumerating templates is concerned (a dialog being opened only in the case where there is more than one template). My question is what approach is best to get round the fact that a reference to the template list is currently being passed to the dialog on creation, and a selected template is being returned?  Here is the code:

```
void CMtApp::OnFileNew()
{
CString s;

if (m_templateList.IsEmpty())
    {
    TRACE0("Error : no document templates registered with CWinApp\n");
    AfxMessageBox(AFX_IDP_FAILED_TO_CREATE_DOC);
    return;
    }

CDocTemplate* pTemplate = (CDocTemplate*)m_templateList.GetHead();
if (m_templateList.GetCount() > 1)
    {
    // more than one document template to choose from
    // bring up dialog prompting user
    COpenTypeDlg dlg(&m_templateList);
    if (dlg.DoModal() != IDOK)
        return;     // none - cancel operation
    pTemplate = dlg.m_pSelectedTemplate;
    pTemplate->GetDocString(s, CDocTemplate::docName);
    }             
ASSERT(pTemplate != NULL);
ASSERT(pTemplate->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CDocTemplate)));

m_bNew = TRUE;
pTemplate->OpenDocumentFile(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `CWinApp` to the dialog's ctor and the dialog can `GetFirstDocTemplatePosition` and `GetNextDocTemplate` itself. But you don't really need to pass the `CWinApp` because the dialog can use `AfxGetApp` to get it itself.

If you insist on passing a template list then build your own list based on what `GetFirstDocTemplatePosition` and `GetNextDocTemplate` return.

Comment: Thanks for that. In the end, I went for what I thought was the simplest option and passed the CWinapp pointer as "this", and then used GetFirstDocTemplatePosition and GetNextDocTemplate in the dialog to replace the existing code. Thanks again.